# Django - how can I have a field in my model consisting of tuple of integers?

Tags: python, django

I am defining the models for my Django app, and I would like to have a field for a model consisting of a tuple of two (positive) integers.  How can I do this?  I'm looking at the Django Models API reference but I can't see any way of doing this.

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: Well it's a bit technical to explain - I'm working with a data library in the [GAP computer algebra system](www.gap-system.org) in which finite groups have unique pairs of integers which identify them.  I want a model which models these groups in the way they are represented in the data library.

Comment: OK, but why does that need to be the primary key?

Comment: What else do I use?  They are uniquely identified by their so-called Small Group IDs, pairs of integers (N,M), where N is the order of the group and M is an index for the group in the collection of small groups of order N.

Comment: No need to use anything. Django automatically defines an autoincrementing integer field. Don't meddle with it unless you really need to.

Comment: OK, fine, I can use the Auto increment field?  If I just wanted to have a field with a tuple of integers how do I do that?

Comment: Well, ignoring Django's model layer for the moment, how would you store it in a database?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you intend to use them after storing in the database; 2 methods I can think of are:

Option 1)

`models.IntegerField(unique=True)`

now the trick is loading data and parsing it: you would have to concatenate the numbers then have a way to split them back out.

fast would be
Option 2)

`models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(max_length=1024, unique=True)`

not sure how it handles unique values; likely '20,40' is not equal to '40,20', so those two sets would be unique.

or just implement it yourself in a custom field/functions in the model.

Comment: Ah OK, thanks, that gives me an idea, I suppose you can store them as a float `N.M`, where `N` is the first integer and `M` the second.

The `CommaSeparatedIntegerField` seems a good option as well, it's just there aren't many examples of this in the docs.